# Cannot change UIImageView frame in a custom table cell

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom table cell.  In it I have put (via the IB) an image view of a certain frame

In 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', under certain conditions, I would like to modify the frame of this UIImageView, so I write something like:

```
UIImageView *imgv = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
CGRect r = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0);
imgv.frame = r;
```

But nothing expected happens (The frame does move a little though not to where I want, but doesn't change its size at all);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change its size, you have to setup the property to scale its content. Since you cannot do it in interface builder, you have to do it in your code:

```
imgv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Try this:

```
UIImageView *imgv = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
imgv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
CGRect r = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0);
imgv.frame = r;
```

About the position, I'm not sure why it is not working. Can you confirm if still doesn't work?